# Conditional Statement in PostgreSQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, many-to-many, greatest-n-per-group

I have here 3 tables namely:

```
person (
  id int PRIMARY KEY
 ,fullname text)

phonenumber (
  id int PRIMARY KEY
 ,personid int REFERENCES person(id)
 ,phonetypeid REFERENCES phonetype(id)
 ,number text)

phonetype (
 id int PRIMARY KEY
,phonetype text) -- phonetype  'Home', 'Cell', 'Fax', 'Main' etc.
```

Each `person` can have multiple numbers stored in the `phonenumber` table and have different phonetype in the `phonetype` table:

```
| fullname         | number        | phonetype |
| Erwin Macale     | (671)632-3909 | Home      |
| Erwin Macale     | (671)632-3909 | Cell      |
| Erwin Macale     | (671)632-3909 | Main      |
```

I want only to display the phone number of each person with these conditions:

- If he has a 'Home' phonetype number display only the home type drop all his other phonetype numbers.
- If he has no 'Home' number, then display only his 'Cell' number then drop all his other('Fax', 'Main', etc..) numbers.
- A person can have no phonenumber.

I created a temporary table which contains `fullname, number, phonetype` named `testable` then from here I separated all phonetype numbers like:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE home AS SELECT * FROM testable WHERE phonetype ILIKE 'home';
CREATE TEMP TABLE cell AS SELECT * FROM testable WHERE phonetype ilike 'cell';
CREATE TEMP TABLE main AS SELECT * FROM testable WHERE phonetype ilike 'main';
CREATE TEMP TABLE fax AS SELECT * FROM testable WHERE phonetype ilike 'fax';
CREATE TEMP TABLE work AS SELECT * FROM testable WHERE phonetype ilike 'work';
CREATE TEMP TABLE neighbor AS SELECT * FROM testable WHERE phonetype ilike 'neighbor';
CREATE TEMP TABLE other AS SELECT * FROM testable WHERE phonetype ilike 'other';
CREATE TEMP TABLE unknown AS SELECT * FROM testable WHERE phonetype ilike 'unknown';
```

and then create another set of temp tables that I think satisfy the above conditions:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE all_cell AS SELECT * FROM cell EXCEPT SELECT * FROM home;
CREATE TEMP TABLE all_main AS (SELECT * FROM main) EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM home UNION SELECT * FROM cell);
CREATE TEMP TABLE all_fax AS (SELECT * FROM fax) EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM home UNION SELECT * FROM cell UNION SELECT * FROM main);
CREATE TEMP TABLE all_work AS (SELECT * FROM work) EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM home UNION SELECT * FROM cell UNION SELECT * FROM main UNION SELECT * FROM fax);
CREATE TEMP TABLE all_neighbor AS (SELECT * FROM neighbor) EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM home UNION SELECT * FROM cell UNION SELECT * FROM main UNION SELECT * FROM fax UNION SELECT * FROM work);
CREATE TEMP TABLE all_other AS (SELECT * FROM other) EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM home UNION SELECT * FROM cell UNION SELECT * FROM main UNION SELECT * FROM fax UNION SELECT * FROM work UNION SELECT * FROM neighbor);
CREATE TEMP TABLE all_unknown AS (SELECT * FROM unknown) EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM home UNION SELECT * FROM cell UNION SELECT * FROM main UNION SELECT * FROM fax UNION SELECT * FROM work UNION SELECT * FROM neighbor UNION SELECT * FROM other);
```

Finally selecting all the unions of the last set of temp tables:

```
SELECT fullname, number, phonetype FROM (
    SELECT * FROM home
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM all_cell
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM all_main
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM all_fax
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM all_work
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM all_neighbor
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM all_other
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM all_unknown
) AS t1
ORDER BY t1.fullname, t1.phonetype;
```

Are the steps to satisfy my conditions right?
I'm still getting different phonetype values from one person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You went to a lot of trouble to get what this single query can give you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.fullname, p.id)
       p.fullname, n.number, t.phonetype
FROM   phonenumber n 
JOIN   person      p ON p.id = n.personid
JOIN   phonetype   t ON t.id = n.phonetypeid
LEFT   JOIN (
   VALUES
     (1, 'home')
    ,(2, 'cell')
    ,(3, 'main')
    ,(4, 'fax')
    ,(5, 'work')
    ,(6, 'neighbor')
    ,(7, 'other')
    ,(8, 'unknown')
   ) r(rnk, phonetype) USING (phonetype)
ORDER  BY p.fullname, p.id, r.rnk;
```

`DISTINCT ON (p.fullname, p.id)` because `fullname` is probably not unique. I use it anyway to get the sort order you seem to be looking for in a single query level.

Details about `DISTINCT ON` in this related answer:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

I appended the ranking (`r.rnk`) information with a [`VALUES` expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-values.html) to make it work with your presented table layout. Better, though, you add to the table `phonetype` permanently:

```
ALTER TABLE phonetype ADD COLUMN rnk int;

UPDATE phonetype t
SET    rnk = r.rnk
FROM  (
       VALUES
         (1, 'home')
        ,(2, 'cell')
        ,(3, 'main')
        ,(4, 'fax')
        ,(5, 'work')
        ,(6, 'neighbor')
        ,(7, 'other')
        ,(8, 'unknown')
       ) r(rnk, phonetype)
WHERE   r.phonetype = t.phonetype;
```

Then your query becomes **even simpler**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.fullname, p.id)
       p.fullname, n.number, t.phonetype
FROM   phonenumber n 
JOIN   person      p ON p.id = n.personid
JOIN   phonetype   t ON t.id = n.phonetypeid
ORDER  BY p.fullname, p.id, t.rnk    -- add more columns to break ties (if any)
```